# What is the best way to solve Ansible map filter error when an attribute is not defined?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of interfaces with attributes such as ip, vrf, etc. The most interesting attribute to me is vrf. I used the map attribute to filter this list and create the necessary code with the reduced unique list. What is the most elegant way to filter this list if one of the supplied interfaces does not have the vrf defined?

variables

```
base:
  HOSTNAME: MVPS001R01
  SITE_NUMBER: 20
  ROUTER_NUMBER: 1
  MGMT_IP: 100.64.1.1
  interfaces:
    - intf: LOOP0
      ip: 100.64.1.1
      vrf: MPLS1
      type: LOOP
    - intf: GI0/0/0
      vrf: global
      ip: 192.168.0.1/24
      type: eth
      peering:
    - intf: GI0/0/1
      vrf: INET1
      ip: 1.1.1.1/30
      type: eth
    - intf: GI0/1/0
      vrf: MPLS1
      ip: 172.31.0.45
      vlan: 2010
      type: eth
```

Jinja2 code:

```
{% set VRFS = base.interfaces | map(attribute='vrf') | list | unique %}

{% for transport in transports %}
{% for vrf in VRFS %}
{% if transport.name | upper == vrf | upper %}

vrf definition  {{ transport.name | upper }}
  rd 1:{{ transport.priority | int }}
  !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```

Output When all interfaces have 'vrf' defined

```
vrf definition  MPLS1
 rd 1:100
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !

vrf definition  INET1
 rd 1:200
!
address-family ipv4
exit-address-family
```

Output when vrf is missing from one of the interfaces

```
interfaces:
- intf: LOOP0
  ip: 100.64.1.1
  vrf: MPLS1
  type: LOOP
- intf: GI0/0/0
  ip: 192.168.0.1/24
  type: eth
  peering:

TASK [deploy-smartwan : Generate Base Configuration File] *******************************************************************************************
fatal: [router1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'vrf'"}
```

It is possible that the vrf attribute may not be set. How do I account for this and efficently handle this?

Comment: "*What is the most elegant way to filter this list if one of the supplied interfaces does not have the vrf defined?*" -- What is your expected output?  And what are the criteria for evaluation of the "elegance" (which you asked for)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The expected output should create one instance of each VRF defined. If an interface does not have a VFF then it should not be created. I think that I need to take the original list of interfaces loop through and find each item that has VRF defined and then add that item to another list. After the new list is defined then I can use the map filter without risk of it resulting in an error because of a single interface that does not have a VRF defined.

Answer (score 7):

By adding selectattr filter I was able to select only items from the base.interfaces where the vrf attribute is defined. This I believe isa very elegant way to reduce the list of elements to what is necessary to generate the configuration.

```
{% set VRFS = base.interfaces | selectattr("vrf", "defined") | map(attribute='vrf') | list | unique %}

{% for transport in transports %}
{% for vrf in VRFS %}
{% if transport.name | upper == vrf | upper %}

vrf definition  {{ transport.name | upper }}
 rd 1:{{ transport.priority | int }}
!
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
!
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}   
{% endfor%}
```

Variables

I have a list of interfaces with attributes such as ip, vrf, etc. The most interesting attribute to me is vrf. I used the map attribute to filter this list and create the necessary code with the reduced unique list. What is the most elegant way to filter this list if one of the supplied interfaces does not have the vrf defined?

variables

```
base:
  HOSTNAME: MVPS001R01
  SITE_NUMBER: 20
  ROUTER_NUMBER: 1
  MGMT_IP: 100.64.1.1
  interfaces:
    - intf: LOOP0
      ip: 100.64.1.1
      vrf: MPLS1
      type: LOOP
    - intf: GI0/0/0
      ip: 192.168.0.1/24
      type: eth
      peering:
    - intf: GI0/0/1
      vrf: INET1
      ip: 1.1.1.1/30
      type: eth
    - intf: GI0/1/0
      vrf: MPLS1
      ip: 172.31.0.45
      vlan: 2010
      type: eth
```

Output

```
vrf definition  MPLS1
 rd 1:100
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !

vrf definition  INET1
 rd 1:200
!
address-family ipv4
exit-address-family
```